# Ionic weird 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' issue

Tags: android, laravel, ionic-framework

Hello i built my ionic app, it worked, on a whole lot of devices, then just a couple of hours ago i tried to run the app on my phone and i noticed that for some reason data wasn't being returned from my web server.  So i tried to run the app on my computer using `ionic serve` to see what was wrong and i noticed this error kept popping up every time i tried to make an $http request:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100'
```

My app has been running perfectly for weeks now, i do not know what could have changed to cause this.  I use google canary for development, i have disabled web security.  But even if the issue was with my browser that still does not explain why the app doesn't work on my phone in particular now.  I was thinking it might have something to do with a new android update or something.

The only changes i have made to my computer recently are uninstalling my norton security antivirus and installing malwarebytes anti-malware and anti-exploit.

I have installed [laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) on my server.  And set the setting at default like this:

```
<?php

return [
    /*
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Laravel CORS
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |

     | allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods can be set to array('*') 
     | to accept any value, the allowed methods however have to be explicitly listed.
     |
     */
    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT',  'DELETE'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
    'hosts' => [],
];
```

I currently have no idea what is going on, i use a lenovo A6000 android phone for development.  The android system webview version is 47.0.2526.100, the android OS version is 5.0.2.

I just installed the app on an old nokia x "android phone" with an android version of 4.1 and it works.

Let me clarify, by "not working" i mean all $http requests, the app itself opens and works normally.

Comment: add this to your php files at the top (just after <?php) and see if it helps -- (header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); )

Comment: Actually i use laravel so i have quite a number of .php files, tried adding that to my main index.php file and the api returned a 500 internal server error.

Comment: Then im not sure. I had the exact issue due to using IP address and not a domain name for my servers and that line allowed any origin header, but then again im not using a PHP framework

Comment: Do i need to set the headers to from ionic before every request?

Comment: dont think so, it works fine when i use Jquery mobile framework or Google polymer using a webview. I think its the server end that has an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so my issue like I described in my post worked on some devices and not on some devices.  I have no idea why.

As to the cause of the issue, why this started happening, once again i have no idea why.

In an attempt to try and resolve the issue i installed CORS with the following default settings:

```
<?php

return [
    /*
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Laravel CORS
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |

     | allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods can be set to array('*')
     | to accept any value, the allowed methods however have to be explicitly listed.
     |
     */
    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
    'hosts' => [],
];
```

When the above didn't work I decided to check my server to make sure I had the **Headers** module installed because i noticed the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header wasn't being included in my response headers from the server.

I then proceeded to directly configuring my **.htaccess** file by adding this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials false
</IfModule>
```

However the above still did not make any difference at least not untill i commented out the **global** CORS middleware in my **Kernel.php** file.

It works perfectly now. :)

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix, put plain php headers in the very beginning of **index.php**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Key, Authorization");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, PATCH");
```

This will work with any laravel version. Then figure out laravel and laravel-cors package versions and fix this in a proper way.

Comment: When i do this now i only get a 403 forbidden error, i should however point out that i said it used to work with my browser and on my phone but even though it may not work on them now it works on some other devices.

Comment: The star * may not work in some cases, try to specify the actual domain. Also, use postman to check the actual response, you can send exactly the same request with postman as you do on the device.

Comment: The actual domain? What will be the actual domain in this case since the request is being made directly form the phone.